# Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality in Lorentz spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality states that if $1<p<q<\infty$, $1/r=1-1/p+1/q$, then we have
$$\left\|\frac{1}{|x|^{n/r}}\ast f\right\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^n)}\le\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb R^n).}$$

Note that here $q=\infty$ is not allowed. My question is, is it possible to get some bounds for $q=\infty$, if we weaken the RHS norm to be in Lorentz space $L^{p,1}$:

$$\left\|\frac{1}{|x|^{n/r}}\ast f\right\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^n)}\le\|f\|_{L^{p,1}(\mathbb R^n).}$$

Any comments/references are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: In the Further Results section of Chapter V, *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions*, Stein refers to a [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077374532) of R. O'Neil for a treatment of fractional integration in the setting of Lorentz spaces. You might look there.

Comment: @Matt Thanks! It seems to me that R. O'Neil's paper also excludes the possibility for $q$ to be $\infty$, maybe it's not possible to have $q=\infty$ in this kind of bounds.

Comment: The $q=\infty$ case follows from the duality of $L^{p,1}$ and $L^{p',\infty}$.  This is not difficult to prove, but I don't know of a precise reference (you could try Grafakos's text, perhaps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Young inequality in Lorentz spaces covers these cases: if $p_1,p_2,p\in]1,\infty[$, $q_1,q_2,q\in[1,\infty]$,
    \begin{equation}
        \|f\ast g\|_{L^{p,q}}\leq C\|f\|_{L^{p_1,q_1}}
        \|g\|_{L^{p_2,q_2}},\qquad p_1^{-1}+p_2^{-1}
        =1+p^{-1},\ q_1^{-1}+q_2^{-1}\geq q^{-1};
    \end{equation}
and if $p_{1},p_2\in ]1,\infty[$,
    $q_1,q_2\in[1,\infty]$, then
    \begin{equation}
        \|f\ast g\|_{L^\infty}\leq C\|f\|_{L^{p_1,q_1}}
        \|g\|_{L^{p_2,q_2}},\qquad p_1^{-1}+p_2^{-1}
        =1,\ q_1^{-1}+q_2^{-1}\geq1.
    \end{equation}
Note that the second inequality contains your estimate.

The oldest reference I know for this is a paper by R.O'Neil, Convolution operators and $L(p,q)$ spaces, Duke Math. J. 30 (1963), 129-142.

Answer (score 0):

The right substitute for $L^{\infty}$ is the space [$BMO$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation), in the following sense: Singular integral operators in $L^1$ is not bounded from $L^1$ to itself, but is bounded from $H^1$ to $L^1$. Hence, by duality, these operators are bounded from $L^\infty$ to $BMO$.

Comment: I note that Wikipedia says: "The space of functions of bounded mean oscillation (BMO), is a function space that, in some precise sense, plays the same role in the theory of Hardy spaces $H^p$ that the space $L^\infty$ of essentially bounded functions plays in the theory of $L^p$-spaces:". Thanks for pointing this out, but a little more detail would have been more helpful to justify this claim.

Comment: The right substitute for $L^{\infty}$ is the BMO space in the following sense: Singular integral operators in $L^1$ is not bounded from $L^1$ to itself, but is bounded from $H^1$ to $L^1$. Hence, by duality, these operators are bounded from $L^\infty$ to $BMO$.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited this into the answer.